# Can someone give me an exampleof union of sigma-algebras which is not a sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I was reading notes on the filtrations and stopping times where I came across this fact: Union  of $\sigma$-algebra is not $\sigma$-algebra in general. I am having difficult time comprehending this, so can someone please exemplify this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/the-union-of-a-strictly-increasing-sequence-of-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigm

Comment: @njguliyev That post addresses a more difficult problem.

Comment: What are you having difficulty comprehending?

Comment: @DonLarynx I think its \sigma-algebra in general, have not yet gotten feel about it. I guess I am in that part of mathematics where I should leave the intuition behind.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{\,E\subseteq \mathbb R\mid [0,2)\subseteq E\lor E\cap[0,2)=\emptyset\,\}$
and $B=\{\,E\subseteq \mathbb R\mid [1,3)\subseteq E\lor E\cap[1,3)=\emptyset\,\}$. Then $A\cup B$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra because $\{0\}\in B$, $\{2\}\in A$, but $\{0,2\}\notin A\cup B$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the universe $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$ and the sigma-algebras $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ generated by $\{a\}$ and by $\{b\}$ respectively (*can you write down $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ in extension?*). Then $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are both in $\mathcal A\cup\mathcal B$ but not $\{a\}\cup\{b\}$ (*can you show this?*). Thus, $\mathcal A\cup\mathcal B$ is not a sigma-algebra.

Comment: $\mathscr{A}=\{\Omega, \phi, a, \{b,c\} \}$ 
$\mathscr{B}=\{\Omega, \phi, b, \{a,c\} \}$.
Thus $a, b \in \mathscr{A} \cup \mathscr{B}$ but $\{a,b\} \not\in \mathscr{A} \cup\mathscr{B} $.