# Understanding previous counterexample about countable infinite union of increasing sigma algebras is not sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, measure-theory

This question has been asked a couple of times before but I have been strugling trying to understand the previous explanations. I want to understand it concisely with an easy counterexample. So far, I have been trying to understand the first answer of the following post:

[Example where union of increasing sigma algebras is not a sigma algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/example-where-union-of-increasing-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigma-algebra/785653)

The idea in  this answer is to take $X= \mathbb{N}$, then  $\lbrace 1,2,...,n\rbrace$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, an then consider the sigma algebra  for each of this sets, i.e $A_{n}= \sigma (\lbrace 1...,n \rbrace)$. Obviously each $A_{n}$ is a sigma algebra and $A_{n} \subseteq A_{n+1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (i.e the sequence is increasing).

So now we want to prove that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{k}$ is not a sigma algebra. After this things become more difficult to understand. But If I understand right, he takes a set $F_{2n}=\lbrace 2,4,....,2n \rbrace$ and this set belong to $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ because for example $4 \in F_{2n}$ we have that $4 \in A_{4}=\sigma (\lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace)$ and it belongs in general to every $A_{n}$ for $n \geq 4$. Proving $F_{2n} \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ but by definition of union $F_{2n}$ should belong to some $A_{k}$ and he argues this doesnt happen which I dont understand since $F_{2n}$ is a subset of $A_{2n}$ right? Also I dont understan the scheme of the proof I mean why this proves this is not a sigma algebra?

I would appreciate a nice explanation of the answer there,thanks!

Comment: Your description is missing something: $\sigma(\{1,\dots,n\})\not\subseteq\sigma(\{1,\dots,n+1\})$.

Comment: So how Im suppose to take the increasing sequence of sigma algebras?

Comment: In that answer, $A_n$ is defined as the collection of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ along with their complements in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You want to set $A_n=\sigma(\mathcal P(\{1,\dots,n\}))$.

Comment: Thanks! But still trying to undestand the proof with the the sigma algebras you both pointed me as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $A_n$ is a set of subsets (namely for a fixed $n$, $A \in A_n$ iff $A$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ or the complement of such a subset). In particular each $A \in A_n$ is finite (the first case), or the complement of a finite set (the second case)

By definition of a union $A \in \bigcup_n A_n$ (a union of set of subsets is again a set of subsets) iff there is some $n$ such that $A \in A_n$.

And for no $n$ can we say that $\bigcup_n F_{2n}$ is in $A_n$, because the union is not finite, and not the complement of a finite set (the complement consists of the set of all odd integers). So it is **not** in $\bigcup_n A_n$. That $4 \in F_{2n}$ is true, but that's not relevant, the **whole set** has to be in one of the $A_n$ or it's not in the union of the $A_n$.

Comment: Now is all clear!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The increasing union of $A_n$ captures exactly the subsets of $\Bbb N$ that are either finite or cofinite.  But there are plenty of sets (such as the even numbers) that are (a) a countable union of finite sets but (b) are neither finite nor cofinite.  Since the set of even numbers is a countable union of sets within $\cup A_n$, but is not itself within that union, it follows that $\cup A_n$ is not a $\sigma-$algebra.