# the union of $\sigma$-field generated by random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Suppose we have a sequence of $\sigma$-field generated by random variables $\mathscr F_{n}$, where $\mathscr F_{n}=\sigma(X_{1},\dots, X_{n})$

$(1)$Can we say that $\mathscr F_{n}$ is an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-field, which means $\mathscr F_{n} \subset \mathscr F_{n+1}$?

$(2)$ $\cup_{n}\mathscr F_{n}$ is a field, or a $\sigma$-field? How to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is affirmative but not the second.

(1) By definition, $\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are all measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$. If $X_1,\dots,X_n,X_{n+1}$ are measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$, then surely so do $X_1,\dots,X_n$, so $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$ is a $\sigma$-field which $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are measurable with respect to. Since $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field with such a property, we must have $\mathcal{F}_n \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$.

(2) The axiom that is stopping the union from being a $\sigma$-algebra is the countable union of events being an event as well. Refer to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/example-where-union-of-increasing-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigma-algebra) for a counterexample.