# A question on a step of Kolmogorov existence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Hi All: I finally found a proof of the Kolmogorov extension theorem that I've been able to follow for the most part ( it's at the link below ). But recently I got stuck. At the beginning of section 1.4, they start out with "Let $F$ be the set of all measurable cylinder sets in $R^{\infty}$.  Then, a few sentences down, they state that $F$ is not a sigma algebra but $F_{n}$ is ? I didn't know to write the $F$ that they use but my question is why $F$ is not a sigma algebra but $F_{n}$ is. They seem like the same thing to me ? I realize that it's a lot to ask and the help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

[https://www.math.lsu.edu/~sengupta/7360f09/kolmogorov.pdf](https://www.math.lsu.edu/%7Esengupta/7360f09/kolmogorov.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

### Why $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a sigma algebra.

- $\mathcal{F}_n$ contains $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots = \mathbb{R}^\infty$.
- If $(E \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots) \in \mathbb{F}_n$, then its complement is $E^c \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$ which is also in $\mathbb{F}_n$.
- Similarly check that $\mathcal{F}_n$ is closed under countable unions by writing out members of $\mathcal {F}_n$ in the form $E \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$.

### Why $\mathcal{F}$ is not a sigma algebra.

The text says

> $\mathcal{F}$ is not a sigma algebra since it is not closed under countably infinite unions.

Consider
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(\underbrace{\mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}}_{k-1} \times \{0\} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots\right).$$
This is the union of sets in $\mathcal{F}$, since it can be written as
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(E_k \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \right),
\text{ where $E_k := \underbrace{\mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}}_{k-1} \times \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$}.$$
But the union cannot be written as $E \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots$
for some $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will print out and go through it and then give a check.

Comment: @angryvian: a couple of questions since the notation ( not yours ) confuses me. 1) in the why $F_{n}$ is a sigma algebra section, doesn't one need to take the complement of the R's also ? Why do you only take the complement of $E$ ?  In the section Why $F$ is not a sigma algebra section,  it stated that $F$ contains sets of the form $E \times R \times R \cdots$ with $E$ a Borel set in some $R^{n}$. Then you have $(k-1)$ R's inside the parentheses along with a null set. Why is there not an $E$ in the countable union expression ? Also,  is $n$ equal to $(k-1)$ in your countable union expression.

Comment: @markleeds For your first question, try drawing a picture in two dimensions of $A \times \mathbb{R}$ for some set $A$, and figure out what the complement is. For your second question, I updated my answer to show you why the sets in the union belong to $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: okay. I'll try that. I think one of my ( many ) problems is visualizing these things. thanks. I'll also go through your updated answer.

Comment: I see now why the complement is only taken for A and not R.  If $X_{1}$ is [0,1] then $X_{1} \times R$ is a rectangle with base [0,1] and infinite height so the complement is everything else so it's $X_{1}^{c} \times R$. That makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: angryavian: this is my last bother I promise. Could you give me either an analytical or intutitve explanation of the difference between $F$ and $F_{n}$. Maybe that will help because I still don't see it. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds Are you asking about the difference in terms of the definition? $\mathcal{F}_1 \subset \mathcal{F}_2 \subset \cdots$ is an increasing sequencee of sigma algebras. $\mathcal{F}$ is their union. If you are asking about the difference in terms of $\mathcal{F}_n$ being a sigma algebra but $\mathcal{F}$ not being one: in general the union of sigma algebras is not necessarily a sigma algebra. You can find other examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/example-where-union-of-increasing-sigma-algebras-is-not-a-sigma-algebra).

Comment: Thanks angryavian: I'll check out the link. it sounds helpful.  But what I was really asking was if you compare $F$ to say $F_{n}$ where $n= 38$ for example, what's the difference between them in an intuitive or visual sense ?

Comment: I think that I'm close to getting it but not quite. Let me try to explain my confusion. $F$ is the collection of all cylinders in infinite dimensions so $R \times R \times R \times \cdots R$. What confuses me is $F_{n}$. If it's $R^{n} \times R \times R \times R \times \cdots R$, then what is the difference between $F_{n}$ and $F_{n+1}$. $F_{n+1}$ is, by definition $R^{n+1} \times R \times R \times \cdots R$ so, since the product measure is infinite, doesn't it ends up with the same dimension as $F_{n}$ so they are then identical rather than increasing ?

Comment: @markleeds $F$ is a collection of sets; it is not $R \times R \times \cdots$. Similarly, $F_n$ is a collection of sets of the form $E \times R \times \cdots$ where $E \subseteq R^n$, but it is not $R^n  \times R \times \cdots$. An example of a set in $F_2$ but not in $F_1$ is $[0,1] \times \{3\} \times R \times R \times \cdots$.

Comment: Oh, okay. The $F_{n}$ are sets of products with an  infinite number of R's but the first n of its sets can be any set and not necessarily  $R^n$. I really appreciate your help and learned a lot and I think I understand it now.

Comment: Also, the link you pointed to in unions of sigma algebras was incredibly enlightening also. I forgot to thank you for that. thanks.