# Is the union of rings a $\sigma$ algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Let be $\Omega$ a set ,$(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ring on $\Omega$ so that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Show that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a ring.

If $A_n$ are $\sigma$ algebras does it conclude that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  A_n$ is a $\sigma$ algebra?

I'm pretty much sure that if $A_n$ is a $\sigma$ algebra it will conclude that  $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  A_n$ is a $\sigma$ algebra as well.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When you say ring, do you mean a [ring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets), or a ring in the sense of abstract algebra? Because they are different things. And you are tagging this *both* "abstract algebra" and "measure theory". As for $\sigma$-algebras, the increasing union of $\sigma$-algebras is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra. [Counterexamples here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5121/742).

Comment: I mean in the sense of measure_theory I edited my question

Comment: If you mean in the sense of measure theory, then your idea is nonsense. A ring of sets on $\Omega$ means a collection $\mathcal{R}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ such that if $A,B\in\mathcal{R}$ then $A\cup B\in\mathcal{R}$ and $A\setminus B\in\mathcal{R}$. There is no $+$ to check closure, there is no $\cdot$ to check closure, there is no $0$, and there are no "inverses". You are listing properties of an *algebraic object*, not of the measure-theoretic object. That's why you are struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write (*edit: wrote in a previous version*) doesn't make any sense. You seem to be confusing the algebraic notion of "ring" (a set $R$ together with two binary operations, $+$ and $\cdot$, such that $(R,+)$ is an abelian group, $(R,\cdot)$ is a semigroup, and $\cdot$ distributes over $+$ on both sides), with the notion of "ring" from measure theory.

Given a set $\Omega$, a "ring on $\Omega$" means a nonempty collection $\mathcal{R}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ such that:

1. If $A,B\in\mathcal{R}$ then $A\cup B\in\mathcal{R}$.
2. If $A,B\in\mathcal{R}$ then $A\setminus B\in\mathcal{R}$.

So what you need to check is that if each $\mathcal{A}_n$ satisfies these properties, and $\mathcal{A}_i\subseteq \mathcal{A}_{i+1}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots$, then $\mathcal{R}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{A}_n$ also has these two properties.

As for $\sigma$-algebras, a ring on $\Omega$ is an algebra on $\Omega$ if it is closed under absolute complements (that is, if $A\in\mathcal{R}$ then $\Omega\setminus A\in\mathcal{R}$).  It is a $\sigma$-algebra if it is also closed under countable unions: if $A_n\in\mathcal{R}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\in\mathcal{R}$.

The increasing union of algebras is again an algebra, but [the increasing union of $\sigma$-algebras need not be a $\sigma$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5119/742), as shown in the several exampless at the link.